# How to connect Google cloud storage database with python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm very new with Google cloud and with databases in general, therefore I apologise if I understood the whole logic wrong.

I have a python file where I access database stored on my local drive with sqlite.

Now I want to access the same database but the one which is stored on google cloud storage and use google SQL. I have no idea how can I do that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, your data will be stored in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket or in a Google Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: storage buckets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of question is often out of scope for Stack Overflow.

First, you'll need to adjust your app instead of talking to sqlite, to MySQL (Cloud SQL also has PostgreSQL) first, as there are some differences there.

Next, you'll need to learn about CloudSQL. I'd start here to get the basics:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart

Then you'll need to learn about connecting via an external application:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app

There's several moving parts to learn about to get it up and running securely.

Broadly speaking, for SO, you'll want to go through all this, give it a shot, and if it's not working, come back with specific questions about where you are, what you've done, and preferably, some code of what you're trying to folks have context on what the specific question is.

Good luck!

I see the clarification comment from above that you want to be using storage buckets. For the sake of completeness: You have a couple options there. You could put your assets in Cloud Storage, and if you don't care about people having access to them outside your app, you can make them public, and then they'll have a URL you can just retrieve in your app.

If you don't want them public, then you'll have to have some authentication in your app (a service account) that you add to the app and use the GCS (Google Cloud Storage) APIs to retrieve your assets. It's not too bad, but there's some learning to be done.

Learning about service accounts:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSnzoW4RlaQ

The GCS APIs:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/how-to
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries